# Jquery +html table

Tags: jquery, html

how to find the html or controls of next td using jquery in  an html table?

Comment: Next `td` relative to what? Post some sample HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to read up a little about the jQuery selectors.

```
$(function(){
      alert( $("#idofthetable td").html() );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

`$('table#yourtableid td')` will get you all TDs in specified Table

`$('table#yourtableid td#specific-td').next()` will get you the next element after specified TD

Have a look through the jQuery docs and tutorials:

http://api.jquery.com/next/

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials